MASM615 Int 10h works on dosbox but not on windowXP
I use dosbox on Mac and made an assembly program that uses int 10h(bios interrupt call)to draws a square. And it works fine, but when I tried to run the program on windowXP emulator on iPad, it seems like the code completely changed the screen ratio and the square is normal either.
Here is the code.
.model small
.stack 100h 
.data
.code
main proc
; Set Graphics Mode
    MOV AX,11h; High Resolution B/W Mode: 640x480 B/W graphics
;Above line Means AH = 00 and AL = 11h
    INT 10h; Selecting Inerrupt for Graphics ;(Video); mode
; Displaying Pixel
    MOV AH, 0Ch; Write pixel on the screen
    MOV AL, 01h ;white Color
    MOV CX,120 ; X- Coordinate as Column # 
    MOV DX,120;  Y- Coordinate as Row #

.repeat
    int 10h
    dec dx
.until(dx==70)

.repeat
    int 10h
    dec cx
.until(cx==70)k[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/WppuMWwX.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/Tp23OBgJ.jpg)

.repeat
    int 10h
    inc dx
.until(dx==120)

.repeat
    int 10h
    inc cx
.until(cx==120)


ClearScreen:
    
    MOV AH, 08h ; input a character from Keyboard withouot displaying on the screen
    INT 21h
    
.IF AL != 13
    JMP ClearScreen
.ENDIF
; Shifting Video Mode to Text Mode Means it Clears the Screen
    mov al , 03 ; function code for setting the text mode.
    mov ah,0    ; Video Mode
    int 10h     ; Switching from Video Mode to Text Mode

mov ah,4ch      ; Terminate program
int 21h
main endp
end main         ; End of program

Pictures of two terminals are shown in the pictures.
terminal of window XP on iPad emulator 
terminal of dosbox on Mac 
I’m really not sure where the problem is so I don’t knows what to try. But I expect dosbox and windowXP should perform the same way.

Does it fails on a WinXP emulator? Try it on a real Windows. It could be a bug in the emulator itself.

@Alejandro I agree that it's probably a bug in the emulator, but these days it's very difficult to find, install and register a copy of 32-bit Windows (modern Windows is 64-bit only, which won't run this 16-bit program).
